# examples of Design Patterns

Tags: java, design-patterns

I was asked in a job interview to give examples of design patterns and how they are used in the JVM implementation? I was stumped -- can anyone suggest answers so I'll know what to say if I'm ever asked again?

Comment: A very straightforward one would be the Observer Pattern with [Observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Examples of GoF Design Patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns)

Comment: You probably mean the JDK rather than the JVM...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Java  `File IO` library is based on `Decorator pattern`.
2. Java `Collections sort()` uses `Strategy pattern`.
3. There is inbuilt support for  `Observer Pattern`  in JDK, By using
   `Observable` class and `Observer` interface, you can have `Observer
   Pattern`
4. `Singleton Pattern` in used in `Runtime` class, where you can have
   only one object of type 'Runtime', by accessing `getRuntime()`
   method.